# if( $_POST['id'] is set){...} else if ($_GET['id'] is set){...}

Tags: php, post, get

This is psuedocode:

```
if( $_POST['id'] is set){
   $id = $_POST['id']
}else if($_GET['id'] is set){
   $id = $_GET['id']
}
```

How can this be writ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

perhaps, however, you'd rather just use [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
```

The precedence of `_POST`, `_GET`, and `_COOKIE` can be set via configuration directives.

Answer (score 3):

Use `isset`:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
   $id = $_POST['id'];
} else if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id']
}else if( isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = isset($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:(isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:"");
```